# Nodejs + expressjs replays request after server timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to import huge amount of data in a node + express app via `app.get("/importdata" , callback)`.  At the timeout and if the request is not complete, it replays the request again and my server starts importing the same data again.

I am not able to find the exact reason why the request is being replayed after the connection timeout?

A portion of problem is solved if I set my timeOut period to some huge number but I am not understanding exactly why the request is played again?

Thanks a lot in advance.

piece from my server.js

```
app.get('/impdata', function(req, res){
req.connection.setTimeout(600000);
console.log("impstore--------------->");
Q.when( getData(req.data), function(resp){
    res.json(resp);
}); });
```

Piece from my console

```
impstore--------------->
userid 
time stamp Wed Oct 24 2012 16:35:28 GMT+0530 (IST)
Listings got 100
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 200
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 300
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 400
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 500
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 600
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 700
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 800
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 900
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
impstore--------------->
userid 
time stamp Wed Oct 24 2012 16:37:28 GMT+0530 (IST)
Listings got 1000
userid 
ims 1
time stamp recursive
Listings got 100
userid 
ims 1
```

For information : I am getting data in chunks of 100
I receive 900 data listings and then the server times out but as we can see on the console the request is made again check the last 2 sets , 1st one shows the next 100 i.e listings now increase to 1000 and the second one says listings are 100 and when the whole process is complete , U have 2 similar objects .

Hopefully I explained well.

Comment: You need to show some code (preferably a minimal test case).

Comment: You need to show some code (preferably a minimal test case).

Comment: Are  you sure it's not the client side that's resending it?

Comment: I have edited the code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I saw another answer here in stack overflow that explains that according to the HTTP protocol specification, an http client can resend a request after a timeout. For express, the default server timeout is 2 minutes ( https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback).

That is possibly your case if you are accessing that endpoint from a browser.

And I understand the weirdness of this, it looks like a ghost is re-sending the same requests to you. Other people asks to you over and over again to double check if it is no the client re-sending the requests.

I'll update this answer if I find the other answer with a better explanation of this ghost behavior.

Comment: up, did you find why you had that bug ?